# Writing to a "hot standby" database

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.3

I have a postgres database in machine-1 in a **hot standby** mode which is constantly replicating (**WAL archiving**) the DB present in another machine.

Now I want to directly create a few totally unrelated tables in the machine-1. And I know we don't have write permissions on a DB which is in hot standby mode.

So, do I need to create a new DB (and run 2 DB instances in the same machine) or can I show how make the existing DB (partially) writable by creating a new schema or something else?

**Note:**

1. I am running postgres-9.3 on Ubuntu.
2. Also, I can tweak some settings in the DB replication if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in option in PostgreSQL. You need to change your replication proccess and use third-party tools. For example in Skype they develop nice set of tools for Postgres called [SkyTols](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/skytools). One of them is [Londiste](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Londiste_Tutorial_%28Skytools_2%29) - replication tool which allow read-write replicas.